# Need to convert txt file to CSV (with headers) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Can we convert below txt file to CSV format added at the end?

Text file:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Hostname: 01-any1TEST 
Event Message: Ping
Alert Status: Down at least 3 min
Event Time: 17:25:14
Alert Type: :Windows 2012 Server
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 192.168.1.2
Hostname: 02-any2TEST  
Event Message: Ping
Alert Status: Down at least 4 min
Event Time: 17:25:40
Alert Type: :Unix Server
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IP Address: 192.168.1.3
Hostname: 03-any3TEST 
Event Message: Ping
Alert Status: Down at least 3 min
Event Time: 17:26:21
Alert Type: :windows host 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

CSV file output required as below:

```
'IP Address','Hostname','Event Message','Alert Status','Event Time','Alert Type'
'192.168.1.1','01-any1TEST','Ping','Down at least 3 min','17:26:21','Windows 2012 Server '
'192.168.1.2','02-any2TEST','Ping','Down at least 3 min','17:26:21','unix host '
'192.168.1.3','03-any3TEST','Ping','Down at least 3 min','17:26:21','windows host '
```

Comment: Its possible, have you made any attempt yourself?

Comment: yes .

$input = Get-Content -path "path\Desktop\in.txt" | Select-String -List 'Alert Type','IP Address','Hostname','Event Message','Alert Status','Event Time'
$data = $input[1..($input.Length - 1)]

$maxLength = 0

Comment: $objects = ForEach($record in $data) {
    $split = $record -split "\s{2,}|\t+"
    If($split.Length -gt $maxLength){
        $maxLength = $split.Length
    }
    $props = @{}
    For($i=0; $i -lt $split.Length; $i++) {
        $props.Add([String]($i+1),$split[$i])
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props
}
$headers = [String[]](0..$maxLength)
$headers1 = [String[]]('MachineType','EventTime','HostName','IPAddress','AlertMessage','Severity','AlertType','AlertStatus')


$objects | 
Select-Object $headers |
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "path\out.csv"

Comment: You should edit your question to add your code as comments are not formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
$logFile = "logfile.txt"

$delimeterPattern = '^####'
$recordPattern = '^([^:]+): (.+)'

# how many lines in a record?
$recordLines = Select-String $delimeterPattern $logFile -List |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber

$logContent = Get-Content $logFile
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $logContent.Count; $i += $recordLines ) {
  $output = New-Object PSObject
  for ( $j = $i; $j -lt $i + $recordLines; $j++ ) {
    $logContent[$j] | Select-String $recordPattern | ForEach-Object {
      $output | Add-Member NoteProperty $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
    }
  }
  $output
}
```

To write to a CSV file, put the above in a script and pipe to `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Got below error :
     export-csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: 
     C:\output_temp.csv. The appended object does not have a property 
     that corresponds to the following column: . To continue with 
     mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the 
     command.
     At line:17 char:12
     +   $output| export-csv "$tempfile" -notypeinformation -append

Comment: IF I add -force option still below error :

export-csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At line:17 char:12
+   $output| export-csv "$tempfile" -notypeinformation -append -Force
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: You need to put the above in a script file, example name `getlog.ps1`. Run the script, and pipe the script's output to CSV; e.g. `getlog.ps1 | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation`.

Comment: for this input file it is processing in infinite loop with blank output file .

#####
IP Address: 192.162.1.2
Hostname: test-1-TEST 
AlertStatus:Ping failed
EventTime:01:03:07 
MachineType:Win Server
Alert Type: Ping
Severity: critical
######

Comment: The script I posted works perfectly for the sample data you posted in your question. If your actual input data does not look like the data you posted in the question, then you need to update the question with what the data actually looks like.

Comment: it worked after little modification , thanks for your help .

Comment: In that case it is customary to either post your own answer and mark it as the answer, or alternatively mark this answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will solve your problem:

```
Function Convert2CSV()
{
    param($logFile, $csvFile)

    "'IP Address','Hostname','Event Message','Alert Status','Event Time','Alert Type'" | Out-File  $csvFile 

    get-content $logFile -Delimiter "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" | &{ process{
       $IsValidMatch=$_ -match "IP Address: (.*)\r\nHostname: (.*)\r\nEvent Message: (.*)\r\nAlert Status: (.*)\r\nEvent Time: (.*)\r\nAlert Type: (.*)\r\n"
       if($IsValidMatch)
       {
           $nextLine="'$($matches[1])','$($matches[2])','$($matches[3])','$($matches[4])','$($matches[5])','$($matches[6])'" | Out-File  $csvFile -Append
       }
    }} 
}
```

Finally call the Convert2CSV function, and define your log file and output file as parameter:

```
Convert2CSV -logFile .\1.txt -csvFile 3.txt
```

Comment: it is processing only first record in file . Do we need to add a loop here ?

Comment: try it ;). It will proceed the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$delimeterPattern = '^--'
 $recordPattern = '^([^:]+): (.+)'

$logContent = Get-Content "logfile.txt"

# how many lines in a record?
$recordLines = ($logContent | Select-String $delimeterPattern |
Select-Object -First 1).LineNumber

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $logContent.Count; $i += $recordLines ) {
 $output = New-Object PSObject
 for ( $j = $i; $j -lt $i + $recordLines; $j++ ) {
$logContent[$j] | Select-String $recordPattern | ForEach-Object {
  $output | Add-Member NoteProperty $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value 
$_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value
  }
 }
$output
}
```

Updated seprator $delimeterPattern = '^--' to $delimeterPattern = '^####' .

Comment: Your example source data you put in your question uses `-`, not `#` characters - so of course it didn't work as I originally posted. You have to provide correct information in your question. I updated my answer with `#` and you can mark it as the answer.